# what are address-bound/domain-bound certificates?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a requirement to host **address-bound or domain-bound** certificates in either **DNS CERT records or LDAP servers** that are discoverable by other parties. 
I tried to search on internet about them but didn't got much information.

So basically I need some link or some little explanation about **address-bound or domain-bound** certificates.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X.509 certificates when used for authentication of servers during SSL/TLS handshake include the server's host name or IP address in Subject.CommonName field and/or in the corresponding field SubjectAlternativeName extension. This information restricts the use of the certificate to certain host and also identifies the host. When the client connects to host A using IP address 1 and receives the certificate issued for host B and/or IP address 2, this is an evidence of either misconfigured server or fake server or stolen certificate. In these cases security of the communication can not be guaranteed.

What you are asking for are not standard terms, that's why you can't find information about them. The certificate can have both host name (or several) and IP address (or several) in it, so the certificate can't be called strictly "something-bound".